# how to play SWF in wxpython's panel in linux

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, flash

i'm stuck again, now i'm stuck with flash player in wxpython linux. i'm using wxpython 2.8.12 and python 2.7 in linux mint.

wxpython in windows has wx.lib.flashwin.FlashWindow. all you need to do is
`from wx.lib.flashwin import FlashWindow`
i learn it from [here](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216845/play-flash-files-with-wxpython)

but how about in linux? is there any module that come close to FlashWindow but run well in linux?

how about create a simple browser in panel, like wx.html2? sadly this module doesn't exist in wxpython 2.8. even if it is, is it possible to run flash?

oh and change wx version is not an option for my current state. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You won't be able to run Flash if you cannot use `wx.lib.flashwin` in Linux. The [webview](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html) widget is what you want, but you would have to  upgrade your wxPython version to get it. Since you said you cannot do that, then you won't be able to use Flash with wxPython on Linux.

Comment: darn it. anyway thank you for the reply. it safes me from googling around too much. really appreciate it.